# Is this an api or a routes or an endpoint or just a get method in nodejs app?

Tags: node.js, api, endpoint, getmethod

I have studied nodejs backend development for a while and last time when my friend discussed an nodejs project with me.

He referred to a piece of code listed below as api. 
Here is how the code looks like:

```
app.get('/home',(res,req)=>{
    res.sendFile('views/index.html', {root: __dirname });
});
```

So, is this piece of code an api or an endpoint or a route or just a get method in nodejs app?

Comment: It is an API endpoint, served by a (most probably) Express route. It is not a `get` method as it is `post`, which is really interesting.

Comment: thank you, my apology. I just updated my question. So, its app.get()...